# Pass decimal value to django model from formated input

Tags: jquery, html, django

I, have a DecimalField in Django model and form, likewise I, have an input in html form, with comma as thounsand separator and dot for decimal separator (123,456.78), formated with jquery plugin [Cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/), but when I, try save my form this show a message says: Enter a number.

I' want save the data from the form, with value in decimal without lose the format in html.

*Sorry! my english is too bad.*

Here is my code:

## Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    Price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=17,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                100.00,
                message='>=100')])
```

## Form

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.DecimalField(
        label='Price',
        label_suffix=False,
        max_digits=17,
        decimal_places=2,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': '123,456.78'})
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'price'
        ]
```

## View

```
class NewProduct(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'new_product.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('products:new')

    def get_queryset(self):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        return products

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewProduct, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = self.get_queryset()
        return context
```

## Html

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>      
        <script src="{% static 'js/cleave.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="price" class="price">

        <script>
            new Cleave('.price', {
                numeral: true,
                numeralDecimalMark: '.',
                delimiter: ','
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What is inside your view?

Comment: I, add the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I, solved this problem, subclassing DecimalField class, for not loose original behavior, and creating a new class called Thousands (based on DecimalField class), for overriding to_python function and replacing commas with an empty string ''.

Here is my code.

*This works for me, please if somebody can write a better method and publish here, then I, will be very gratefuly.*

Again, my english es too bad, sorry!.

## Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    Price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=17,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                100.00,
                message='>=100')])
```

## Form

```
from decimal import Decimal, DecimalException

class Thousands(forms.DecimalField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return None
        if self.localize:
            value = formats.sanitize_separators(value)
        value = force_text(value).strip().replace(',', '')

        try:
            value = Decimal(value)
        except DecimalException:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')
        return value


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = Thousands(
        label='Price',
        label_suffix=False,
        max_digits=17,
        decimal_places=2,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': '123,456.78'})
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'price'
        ]
```

## View

```
class NewProduct(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'new_product.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('products:new')

    def get_queryset(self):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        return products

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewProduct, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = self.get_queryset()
        return context
```

## Html

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>      
        <script src="{% static 'js/cleave.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form }}
        </form>

        <script>
            new Cleave('.price', {
                numeral: true,
                numeralDecimalMark: '.',
                delimiter: ','
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```